# How can i sort Cassandra-cql Results by timestamp?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cassandra, cql

Hi how can i sort my entries by the timestamp of the columns?

```
def self.get_users
  @@db.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean timestamp of the values, or is your column key some kind of timestamp?

CQL doesn't support sort - it returns data in the order it is stored on disk.  You tell Cassandra how you want you columns sorted by specifying the comparator_type on your Column Family.  In this case, you might consider using a composite column keys of [timestamp, column name].